# Change tag name in SOAP xml response (field in class and tag in response must be different)

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl2java

I have class like this:

```
@Root(name = "address_v1", strict = false)
public class AddressItem {

    @Attribute(name = "idAddress")
    private Long addressId;

    @Attribute(name = "idClient")
    private Long clientId;
...
}
```

And I have response:

```
...
<ax23:address xsi:type="ax24:AddressItem">
   <ax24:addressId>1111</ax24:addressId>
   <ax24:clientId>1109</ax24:clientId>
...
```

But I need:

```
<ax23:address xsi:type="ax24:AddressItem">
   <ax24:idAddress>1111</ax24:idAddress>
   <ax24:idClient>1109</ax24:idClient>
```

Annotation `@Attribute(name = "idAddress")` doesn't work. (`org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute`).

I use wsdl2java as wsdl creator.

Answer (score 0):

try with following steps and modify your POJO class as given below,

- use `@Element` annotation for XML Element instead of `@Attribute` annotation ([please refer to documentation for more info](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/package-summary.html))

  > The Element annotation is used to represent a field or method that
  >   appears as an XML element.
- set the relevant xml element names to `@Root` and `@Element` annotations

AddressItem.java

```
@Root(name = "ax23:address", strict = false)
public class AddressItem {

    @Element(name = "ax24:addressId")
    private Long addressId;

    @Element(name = "ax24:clientId")
    private Long clientId;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn`t work  
Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(name=idAddress, type=void, data=false, required=true) on field 'addressId' private java.lang.Long

Comment: what is your element name, is it "idAddress" (`@Element(name = "idAddress")`) ?. change it to "ax24:addressId" (`@Element(name = "ax24:addressId")`). please refer AddressItem.java POJO class in above answer